# Compiling with hilatex fails

Tags: e-tex, format

I'm trying out the new-ish [hitex](https://ctan.org/pkg/hitex) format that produces special HINT files made to be viewed on a screen. The plain format seems to work (based on the limited examples I've tried) but the `hilatex` format does not, at least with miktex. Trying to compile the file `aaa.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
some text
\end{document}
```

with `hilatex aaa.tex` produces the log

```
This is HiTeX, Version 3.141592653, HINT version 1.4 (MiKTeX 23.4) (preloaded format=hilatex 2023.4.18)  18 APR 2023 15:47
entering extended mode
entering Prote mode
**aaa.tex 
(aaa.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-03-30> ("article.cls"
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
("size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \tex_splitbotmarks:D 
                                \use:c {c__mark_class_2e-left_mark}
l.640   \onecolumn
                  
?
```

So hitex does not define the etex primitive `\splitbotmarks` (and probably others). Since as far as I know latex requires etex, there is no hope of hilatex working without modification, right? Or am I missing something? After all, `hilatex.ini` contains at the top

```
% $Id: hilatex.ini 62436 2022-03-05 17:45:17Z karl $
% Karl Berry, 2022. Public domain.
```

so I would have guessed there had been some testing of the format.

Comment: the hitex on miktex seems to be outdated. miktex has version 1.4, texlive 2023 has version 2.0.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks! I’ll make a report with miktex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2023/10/5, miktex has hitex 2.0 ([github commit](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/commit/af9843f96e50cc4eddba017ba3ee09160ebc5ff2)) so this should be fixed.